# Double 2x12 Beam - Seams Over Posts?

Tags: wood, roof, construction, beam, lumber

I'm building an awning off the side of a barn. I have four 6x6 posts spacing at 0,8',18',26'(8ft, 10ft, 8ft spans).

I am building a beam out of 2 2x12s. I had learned that when constructing these beams its best for the beam to have the boards spaces evenly. Side 1 = 2 pieces @ 13'; Side 2 = 3 pieces at 5' - 16' - 5'

Putting beam together this way would mean the 5' pieces on side 2 would only be resting on the outer posts. Does this matter? Is the beam, once constructed, considered a single beam and I don't need to worry about parts not resting on posts? OR should I construct the beam so Side 2 pieces all land over top of posts.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your description. A diagram would really help. Beam members need to splice over posts. What else is there to know?

Answer (score 0):

Should have side 1 go to second post, first piece of side 2 goes to first post, second piece of side2 goes to third post.

Keep alternating till the end.  Ends of 2x12s end on a post, each side of 2x12s pieces of beam end on different posts.

Adjust post spacing and/or length/cut of 2x12s you buy/cut.

Works for any number of pieces making up beam.  Three 2x12s will have two long pieces with a short centre to start(or two short/one long).